# Change Multiple CSS property from multiple CSS class dynamically in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, angular

In angular, we can easily change the property of a CSS class dynamically, like if I have a class

```
.my-class {
  background: url('..')
}
```

and if I used my-class as

```
<div class="my-class">
  ------
</div>
```

now, we can change the image effectively by using

[style.background]="url(..)"

like

```
<div class="my-class" [style.background]="getImageUrl()">
    ----
</div>
```

Now, can anyone tell me, is there any solutions if there's have multiple css-class and there I have to change background url all of them, how can I do it?

Like my CSS classes are

```
.my-class-one {
  background: url('..')
}

.my-class-two {
  background: url('..')
}

.my-class-three {
  background: url('..')
}
```

and HTML code is

```
<div class="my-class-one my-class-two my-class-three">
  ----
</div>
```

There I need to change all background image URL by calling angular methods

```
getImageUrlOne()
getImageUrlTwo()
getImageUrlThree()
```

Answer (score 0):

ngClass can be used in html

```
[ngClass]="{'my-class-one': getImageUrlOne(), 'my-class-two': false, 'my-class-three': false}"
```

JS

```
getImageUrlOne(){
   //.... logic to decide my-class-one should be used or not
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set different-different flag variable in each function and when function call then set one flag true. set ngclass as below:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'my-class-one': getImageUrlOne(), 'my-class-two': getImageUrlTwo(), 'my-class-three': getImageUrlThree()}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Set background image dynamically with a `data-` attribute and then apply the value of that attribute to `background-image` in your (S)CSS.

example.component.html:

```
<div class="element" [attr.data-background-url]="backgroundImageUrl"></div>
```

example.component.scss:

```
.element {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  /* use the data attr to set the background img */
  background-image: url(attr(data-background-url));
}
```

example.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example-component',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.scss']
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  backgroundImageUrl: string = "path/to/image.jpg";
}
```